# Adjust a recessed telepost/steel column

Tags: basement, steel, column

I need to lower a bit the teleposts in my house. I have no issues with the procedure per se, but I have issues with access. In particular, I have this situation:

[image]

Besides the cable, the main issues are two fold:

- the notches for a wrench are partially higher than the inspection door, making it hard to reach with a normal wrench;
- even if I can somehow stick a wrench, the notches will be reachable only on certain small portions of the turn.

> What's the way to adjust this post?

If I cannot come up with anything else, I might cut a whole on the other side of the wall (I have access to it), but I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: I honestly don't know if this will work (there might be too much friction), but have you tried locking the thin part with a wrench and turning the large collar on the post with a big pipe wrench?

Comment: Nope, but I'm willing to try :)